# Get BASE_URL from SharedPreferences inside RetrofitBuilder

Tags: java, android

I have created a Settings screen with a field to edit the BASE_URL and store it in Shared Preferences. My question is this: Is it possible to replace the BASE_URL with this value from Shared Preferences on each Call?

Comment: Just put BASE_URL in Retrofit builder class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add Url into SharedPreferance**

```
 SharedPreferenceUtils.putString("URLS","https://www.google.com");
```

**Get Url From SharedPreferance**

```
private static String base_url = SharedPreferenceUtils.getString("URLS","");
 public static String BASE_URL = base_url;

/*** Create an instance of Retrofit object* */


      public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }
```

SharedPreferenceUtils.java

```
public class SharedPreferenceUtils {

        private static SharedPreferences prefs;
        private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        private SharedPreferenceUtils()
        {

        }

 public static void init(Context context) {
        if (prefs == null) {
            prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = prefs.edit();
        }
    }
        public static void putString(String key, String value) {
            editor.putString(key, value);
            editor.commit();
        }



        public static String getString(String key, String defValue) {
            return prefs.getString(key, defValue);
        }
    }
```

Also add AppSingleton class as below

```
public class AppSingleton extends MultiDexApplication {
    private static final String TAG ="AppSingleton" ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferenceUtils.init(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

add this gradel

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

then last thing is to add this class into manifiest as below

```
 <application
        android:name=".AppSingleton"
      />
```

Comment: is it helpfull.

Comment: It's giving me exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ritecare.sharedPReferences.SharedPreferenceUtils.putString(SharedPreferenceUtils.java:23)

Comment: @SheikhAsifIqbal try above updated solution it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:-
I set url from sharedpreference if it is non empty or based url is saved in sharedpreference otherwise it will set static

```
String url = "";

    if (!PersistData.getStringData(activity, ConstValues.api_url).equals("")){

        url = PersistData.getStringData(activity, ConstValues.api_url);
    }
    else {
        url = BASE_URL;
    }



    if (retrofit == null){

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
                .build();
    }
```

*Above, BASE_URL is static string*

PersistData class,

```
public class PersistData {

private static final String PREFS_FILE_NAME = "localData";

/*
 * default value is empty string
 */

public static String getStringData(final Context ctx, String key) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString(key, "");
}


public static String setStringData(final Context ctx, final String key, final String data) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, data);
    editor.commit();
    return key;
}

/*
 * default value is -1
 */


public static int getIntData(final Context ctx, String key) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getInt(key, -1);
}


public static void setIntData(final Context ctx, final String key, final int value) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}


/*
 * default value is false
 */
public static boolean getBooleanData(final Context ctx, String key) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean(key, false);
}


public static void setBooleanData(final Context ctx, final String key, final boolean data) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, data);
    editor.commit();
}



/*
 * default value is 0.0f
 */


public static float getFloatData(final Context ctx, String key) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getFloat(key, 0.0f);
}


public static void setFloatData(final Context ctx, final String key, final float value) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putFloat(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}


/*
 * default value is -1
 */


public static long getLongData(final Context ctx, String key) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getLong(key, -1);
}


public static void setLongData(final Context ctx, final String key, final long value) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong(key, value);
    editor.commit();

    }

}
```

**If you need to set it from several saved sharedpreference value based on condition just check the condition and assign into url string.**

Hope it will help you.